# Two Wireless Routers - network hangs once in a while

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, freeze, wireless-bridge

I've setup two wireless routers at my place with the same SSID, different channels: **Cisco EPC3928AD** is `192.168.150.1`, cable in, has DHCP server on with client IP range starting at `.10`. **Sitecom X6 N900** is `192.168.150.2` static, set to automatic-DHCP, but the DHCP Server for clients is off. Both are hooked up via LAN ports.

Things work fine but every 5m or so, the network just hangs and all communication stops. My torrents come to a halt and Chrome either says "waiting for www.google.com" or "resolving host". I have then to open a new page on the browser to sort of restart the communication. Assuming the problem was with my ISP's DNS servers, I changed to Googles but no success. The issue also happens when I try to reach other devices within the network.

Do you have any suggestion to what the problem/conflict is?

Thanks

Comment: You should clarify how the two routers are connected. Is there a third router? Are they connected on the WAN side or on the LAN side? Are they connected to a switch? Whatever...

Comment: Did you disable NAT on the Sitecom? It shouldn't really come into play if you're really going LAN-port-to-LAN-port, but it's probably good to disable it to be sure.

Comment: the Cisco connects to the internet (WAN port). Then it connects to Sitecom via LAN. I have not disables NAT on the sitecom. I will try that

Comment: I've disabled NAT on the Sitecom but the issue remains. BTW, if I turn the Sitecom off, i get no network freeze…